# Config file of smb in Solaris 11.2

Tags: samba, solaris-11, smbfs

I have a server which is running solaris 11.2. I can login by root, and the smbd service is running in the server, but I cannot detect the place where the samba config file is. Do you know how to find the samba config file?

```
root@backup01:~# ps aux|grep smb
root       960  0.0  0.12265212516 ?        S   2月 09 86:03 /usr/lib/smbd
root       936  0.0  0.0 5336 1796 ?        S   2月 09  0:00 /usr/lib/smbfs/smb
root     20938  0.0  0.0 3164 1212 pts/3    S 18:42:14  0:00 grep smb
root     29317  0.0  0.0 3324 2644 ?        S   3月 02  0:17 smbstat -c 60
root     29320  0.0  0.0 3320 1884 ?        S   3月 02  0:17 smbstat -t 60
root     29323  0.0  0.0 3320 1816 ?        S   3月 02  0:17 smbstat -u 60
```

Comment: FYI: You can of course continue to use Samba but Solaris 11 actually has support for SMB as part of the kernel space, i.e. as part of the OS itself if you like. Just google it. If you are more comfortable using Samba and do not need the added performance and features that the Solaris SMB solution gives you then no problem in using Samba, even though strictly speaking, if the purpose is file sharing using SMB, you no longer need Samba as of Solaris 11.

Answer (score 0):

The following command shows the location of the config file in the first line of output:

```
testparm -d
```